# Install packages in Create R Model - AzureML

Tags: r, azure, machine-learning, r-package, azure-machine-learning-service

Is it currently possible to install packages in 'Create R Model'? Currently this is a huge limitation of AzureML.

I know it is possible to do it in 'Execute R Script' but in 'Execute R Script' you can't save the model.

Comment: What are the packages that you need to use in 'Create R Model' ?

Comment: @HarithaThilakarathne Splitstackshape and its dependency packages.

Answer (score 0):

On using the **Execute R Script** module of Microsoft Azure Machine Learning, there are preloaded packages that are available, and you can call/use them by using the `require()` or `library()` command.

To view the list of supported R packages of Azure Machine Learning, you may refer on [**this link**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt741980.aspx).

Alternatively, if the R package you will be using is not included in the default R packages of Azure Machine Learning, you may refer on [**this link**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjguin/2014/09/24/how-to-upload-an-r-package-to-azure-machine-learning/) to learn **how to use an external R package for Azure Machine Learning**.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your model locally and upload it as a dataset. 
For instance

```
library(kernlab)
rbf <- rbfdot(sigma=0.1)
irisSVM <- ksvm(Species~.,data=iris,type="C-bsvc",kernel=rbf,C=10,prob.model=TRUE)
save(irisSVM, file = "c:/irisSVMmodel.rda")
```

Upload it as a new dataset and in your Execute R Script:

```
library(kernlab)
dataset1 <- maml.mapInputPort(1) # class: data.frame
load("./src/irisSVMmodel.rda");
prediction <- predict(irisSVM, dataset1, type="probabilities")
dataframe <- prediction
index <- which.max(dataframe)
df <- colnames(dataframe)
result <- data.frame(df[index])
maml.mapOutputPort("result");
```

You may read this [post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2018/04/25/deploying-externally-generated-pythonr-models-as-web-services-using-azure-machine-learning-studio/) for more information